# having a problem with setting up parallax scroll

Tags: javascript

Trying to do my first parallax work, but I'm having an abnormal problem 
when I write this code

```
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
    const target = document.querySelector(".kalagh");

    let scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
    let rate = scrolled * 5;


    target.style.transform = "translate3d(0px,'+rate+'px,0px)";
});
```

It doesn't do anything, but when I change rate variable to hard size like 500px it works fine, I've checked the code like billion times and can't understand where I am doing it wrong, BTW it is being done on  a ul which has 3 lis, 1 of them has the class "kalagh".

Answer (score 0):

Eh, you have a typo of mismatched quotation marks: in `"...'...'..."` the `'...'` part is still "inside" the string, you need `"..."` to "bail out" to JS code. Then it works:

```js
window.addEventListener("scroll", function(e) {
    const target = document.querySelector(".kalagh");

    let scrolled = window.pageYOffset;
    target.innerText=scrolled;
    let rate = scrolled * 5;


    target.style.transform = "translate3d(0px,"+rate+"px,0px)";
});
```

```css
.kalagh {
  background-color: red;
  position:absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="kalagh">...</div>
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
```